# p:commandButton inside p:dataTable/p:dataGrid/p:dataList in primefaces/jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I have a p:commandButton inside p:dataGrid (I have also tried to p:dataTable, p:dataList)

The command buttons action listener method is not executed, yet an ajax call is made to the server.

Note that the dataGrid is loaded lazily.

Please find the sample code:

```
    <p:dataGrid id="portfolioView" value="#{controller.values}" var="p"
                      lazy="true" rendered="#{controller.hasValues()}"
                      style="width: 100%" paginator="true"  rows="20" columns="1">
            <p:column id="portfolioViewColumn">
              <h:panelGroup id="portfolioPanel" layout="block"
                            style="width: 95%; padding: 20px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 5px"
                            styleClass="importantpanel_down_less_spread">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
                  <p:graphicImage value="#{controller.photo}" width="60" height="60"/>
                  <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width: 100%" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{controller.user.name}" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.dateString}"
                                  style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; color: #454545/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.portfolioTitle}"
                                  style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; color: #454545"/>
                  </h:panelGroup>
                  <h:panelGroup layout="block" >
                    <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" id="deletePortfolio" value="Delete" title="Delete this portfolio"
                                     styleClass="fs-button-portfolio" actionListener="#{controller.deleteValue(p)}"/>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" id="editPortfolio" value="Edit" title="Edit this portfolio"
                                     styleClass="fs-button-portfolio" actionListener="#{controller.editValue(p)}" />
                  </h:form>
                  </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
    </p:column>
    <p:dataGrid>

public void deleteValue(Portfolio portfolio) {
    try {
      System.out.println("Removing portfolio ...");
      portfolioFacade.remove(portfolio);
      JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Portfolio Removed", "You have deleted a portfolio from your timeline");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Failure", "Sorry! We have failed to remove this portfolio from your timeline.");
    }
  }

public void editValue(Portfolio portfolio) {
      System.out.println("Preparing portfolio edit...");
      this.currentPortfolio = portfolio;
  }
```

I run on glassfish 3.1.2.2, primefaces 3.4, mojarra

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show code of backing bean, at least relevant parts (these two methods, and class definition with annotations)?

Comment: Could you change the scope of backing bean to viewscoped or sessionscoped?

Answer (score 0):

When a command component within an iterating component is been invoked, then JSF will during processing the form submit reiterate over the iterating component in order to find the command being invoked. In order to successfully find it, it thus requires that the `value="#{controller.values}"` and `rendered="#{controller.hasValues()}"` evaluate **exactly** the same during processing the form submit as it did during displaying the form.

Your concrete problem suggests that it didn't. If the `getValues()` returns an incompatibly changed list (i.e. the bean is request scoped and doesn't preserve the list based on a request parameter), or if the `isHasValues()` returns `false`, then JSF won't be able to reiterate over it and thus also not be able to find the command being invoked.

So, in order to solve this problem, you just need to ensure that the `getValues()` and `isHasValues()` returns exactly the same value during processing the form submit as it did during displaying the form. An easy way is to put the bean in the view scope (and make absolutely sure that you aren't doing business logic in getter methods, but only in (post)constructor and (action)listener methods).

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - points 4 and 5.

Comment: I have realized that if i change the DataModel from LazyDataModel to ListDataModel, it works fine. How would one provide this consistency? I initialize the LazyDataModel in the post construct  method of the session scoped bean